# How to bind to angular template reference variable?

Tags: angular

I have old code that looks something like this:

```
<as-split unit="pixel" #mainViewSplit class="custom-gutter" direction="horizontal" 
   gutterSize="2">
  <as-split-area #propertiesContentPanel [size]="(propertiesWidth | async)" 
    [minSize]="350" maxSize="{{propertiesMinimized? minPanelWidth : '*'}}" 
    *ngIf="(propertiesSplitVisible | async)" [order]="splitOrder.properties">
    <app-properties-content-panel></app-properties-content-panel>
  </as-split-area>
  <as-split-area #someContentPanel [size]="(someWidth | async)" [minSize]="350"
    maxSize="{{someMinimized? minPanelWidth : '*'}}" *ngIf="(someSplitVisible | async)"
    [order]="splitOrder.some">
    <app-some-content-panel></app-some-content-some>
  </as-split-area>
</as-split>
```

In the above html there's as-split-component that contains 2 as-split-area directives (https://angular-split.github.io/documentation). Also in the html above there's 2 template reference variables used to reference the 2 as-split-area directives. They are

```
#propertiesContentPanel
```

and

```
#someContentPanel
```

In the class (.ts) files they are referenced like this:

```
@ViewChild('propertiesContentPanel') propertiesContentPanelSplit: SplitAreaDirective;
@ViewChild('someContentPanel') someContentPanel: SplitAreaDirective;
```

In reality there's a lot more of these as-split-areas but for simplicity only 2 are shown. I want to add all the as-split-area directives to the as-split component with ngFor. So the code would look like this:

```
  <as-split unit="pixel" #mainViewSplit class="custom-gutter" direction="horizontal" gutterSize="2">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let splitItem of splitData">
      <as-split-area id="splitItem.id" *ngIf="(splitItem.isVisible | async) 
        [size]="(splitItem.width | async)" [minSize]="splitItem.minSize" 
        maxSize="{{splitItem.isMinimized? minPanelWidth : '*'}}" [order]="splitItem.order">
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="splitItem.template"></ng-container>
      </as-split-area>
    </ng-container>
  </as-split>
```

Above all the templates and related .ts code used in

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="splitItem.template"></ng-container>
```

are omitted for simplicity.

Everything else works but I cannot now reference the as-split-area directives in the code anymore because template reference variables are missing. How can I bind to as-split-area directives in the refactored ngFor-version so that I can still reference them in the class file with the 2 ViewChild I have (propertiesContentPanel and someContentPanel)?

I would like to do something like this:

```
<as-split-area #="splitItem.referenceVariable"
```

But this doesn't work. I have also omitted type of splitItem also from the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax... the `#`  creates a variable which you can then access via `ViewChild()`. You could use a directive (or input) to pass the template to the component instead.

Comment: yes. it is not valid syntax. hence the question.

Comment: all i want to know is how to make the new code like the old code.

Comment: Do you need to know which reference is which (propertiesContentPanel vs someContentPanel)? OR as long as you can get reference to them, you are satisficed?

Comment: I need to know which is which

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically define template reference variable. The feature was requested, but it was closed:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33233

---

But you can work around this by querying all of the `SplitArea` directives, access its order property and add your own logic. Please note that you need to map each `order` to each panel. The idea is to use `order` as the `id` since we can't make any change to `SplitArea` directive. This way, you can give each `SplitArea` a separate treatment according to the `order`.

If you, instead, want to apply the treatment for each type (SomeContent vs. PropertiesContent vs. etcContent),  please check out the **Bonus** section below.

##### example.component.ts

```js
@Component({
 ...
})
export class ExampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  
  @ViewChildren(SplitAreaDirective)
  splitAreas!: QueryList<SplitAreaDirective>;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    
    const propertiesContentPanel = this.splitAreas.find(s => s.order === 0);

    if (propertiesContentPanel) {
       // do your logic here.
    }
  }
}
```

##### example.component.html

```html
<as-split>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let splitItem of splitData">
    <as-split-area id="splitItem.id" 
         *ngIf="(splitItem.isVisible | async)"
         [order]="splitItem.order">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="splitItem.template"></ng-container>
    </as-split-area>
  </ng-container>
</as-split>
```

---

### Bonus:

You can also create a custom directive that accepts a string literal type, append it to the `SplitArea` directive, query it with `@ViewChildren`, then do your logic according to the string literal type.

`SplitData` type also need to include a new property called `templateType` and is of `SplitAreaType` type.

##### myTemplateRef.directive.ts

```js
export type SplitAreaType = 'SomeContent' | 'PropertiesContent'; 

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyTemplateRef]'
})
export class MyTemplateRefDirective {

  public get SplitArea() {
    return this._splitAreaRef;
  }

  constructor(private _splitAreaRef:SplitAreaDirective) {}
  
  @Input()
  public templateType: SplitAreaType = 'SomeContent';
}
```

##### example1.component.html

```html
<as-split>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let splitItem of splitData">
    <as-split-area appMyTemplateRef [templateType]="splitItem.templateType">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="splitItem.template"></ng-container>
    </as-split-area>
  </ng-container>
</as-split>
```

##### example1.component.ts

```js
@Component({
 ...
})
export class Example1Component implements AfterViewInit {
  
  @ViewChildren(MyTemplateRefDirective)
  myTemplateRefs!: QueryList<MyTemplateRefDirective>;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    
    this.myTemplateRefs.forEach(t => {

      if(t.templateType === 'SomeContent') {
         // do something with the SplitArea here.
         t.splitArea.gutterSize = 200;
      } else {
     
      }

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with my question. I'm not trying to pass template into component

Comment: I cannot edit as-split-area (https://angular-split.github.io/)

Comment: also it's a directive, not a component